# JavaScript help: Simple script won't work when calling setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I want to change the exist in a span element every 2 seconds, but it showing only what is in case 0: 'asd'.

Could anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
var n = 0;

function hideVideoSpan(type){
    switch(type)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            $("#hideVideoSpan").html('asd');
            n = 1;
            break;
        }

        case 1:
        {
            $("#hideVideoSpan").html('lol');
            n = 0;
            break;
        }

        default:break;
    }

    setTimeout(hideVideoSpan(n), 2000);
}

hideVideoSpan(n);
```

Comment: lots of people have given the correct answer but all but one haven't indicated why. research on closures and scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling the function, not making a reference

```
setTimeout(hideVideoSpan(n), 2000);
```

Needs to be a closure

```
setTimeout( function(){ hideVideoSpan(n); }, 2000);
```

Comment: only person to mention closures +1

Comment: I +1'd any that at least explained what the op was doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

```
setTimeout(hideVideoSpan(n), 2000);
```

Should be

```
setTimeout(function() {
    hideVideoSpan(n);
}, 2000);
```